# Можно ли использовать одно тире при обособлении пояснительного определения?

Tags: тире, определения, пояснительные

Дано предложение:

*Автор первой, а за ним и автор **второй – поздней фрески** берут за основу одну и ту же композицию.*

По обычным правилам Розенталя это может быть оформлено так: *Автор первой, а за ним и автор **второй, (а именно) поздней фрески** берут за основу одну и ту же композицию.*

Розенталь: 2. Определения, носящие **характер пояснения** (перед ними можно поставить слова а именно, то есть и т. п.), отделяются запятой от поясняемого слова, но после них запятая не ставится: Торчали толстые головни, остатки **прежней, сгоревшей** бани (М. Г.); **Очередной, шестой** том подписного издания на днях поступит в магазин; Он заговорил совсем **другим, серьёзным** тоном. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119

Но автор вместо запятой использовал тире. Мне такое оформление кажется оправданным, но **нужна  ссылка на правило.**

Где бы ее найти?

Comment: Есть такая версия: пояснение должно выделяться тире, так в других темах, а здесь сложилась другая традиция, автор мог об этом не знать и поставить тире по стандарту. Ещё есть такая версия: когда запятая, надо анализировать, однородные там или другие, автор мог захотеть однозначности, чтоб было предельно ясно.

Comment: *А автор ставил знаки по слуху, не по правилам (она их вообще не знала)* — тогда первая версия верна. Запятая не должна стоять при пояснении, потому что этому знаку вообще не свойственно выражение смысловых отношений, просто сложилась такая традиция. Почему? Два прилагательных — слишком мелкие фигуры, чтоб ставить тире.

Answer (score 1):

Тире можно поставить по аналогии с правилом между подлежащим и сказуемым:
*вторая – это поздняя фреска*.

И вот такая структура вмонтирована в предложение в качестве дополнения.

Слово "это", в принципе, подставляется и в само предложение:
*Автор первой, а за ним и автор второй – это поздней фрески берут за основу одну и ту же композицию.*

Comment: Спасибо за предложения, но нет. Мне не нужно "как бы, в принципе и в качестве". Мне нужны доказательства, что тире можно оставить, то есть ссылка на правило или хотя бы пример из хорошего художественного текста, где такая конструкция используется.

Comment: Вроде бы правила Розенталя самые полные. Вряд ли кто-то выводил дополнительные. Но что-то может употребляться по аналогии с основными правилами. Это похоже на тему "Обособленные приложения", но тут существительные (первое подразумевается) совпадают (*второй [фрески] — поздней фрески*). Ещё с помощью тире автор показывает важность этого уточнения. Разница такая: *второй, (а именно) поздней фрески; второй — (которая является) поздней фрески*. То есть определяется значение понятия "вторая".

Comment: Что показывает автор — я знаю.  Почему автор поставил тире, я знаю тоже. И вы, кстати, могли бы  догадаться, в чём тут дело и где аналогия (проверка на внимательность). Правила, может быть,  и не найти (хотя это и не факт), но нужен хотя бы пример из текста.

Comment: "*догадаться, в чём тут дело и где аналогия*" — что вы имеете в виду? Тут явно тире между определяемым понятием и определением (этого понятия).

Comment: Уважаемая @Sharon, так каков же ответ, какое правило? Я, признаться, уже час кручу в голове этот вытащенный ботом из небытия вопрос. Пока что пришло на ум две вещи: 1) некая аналогия с правилом, что если приложение стоит перед определяемым словом, то второе тире опускается (я решил, что при перестановке Вашего примера второе тире было бы уместно: *"автор поздней — второй — фрески..."*; 2) простой ответ, что тут всунуто авторское интонационное тире, которым можно заменить едва ли не любую запятую в мире.

Comment: У oleedd  наиболее близко к истине следующее утверждение из комментария:  "Ещё с помощью тире автор показывает важность этого уточнения".  Но не хватает четкого пояснения,  это только версия, а в ответе эта тема не раскрыта вовсе.

Comment: Важность — да, но тире не считаю интонационным. Потому что там пояснительные отношения, с тире они сильнее выражены (*вторая фреска — это та, что поздняя*). По всей видимости, такая пунктуация не является стандартной, то есть распространённой, поэтому и в правилах нету.

Answer (score 0):

Комментарий

«Когда это было, Когда это было? Во сне? Наяву? Во сне, наяву, По волне моей памяти Я поплыву..." Уважаемый Nektoid! Где вы были 25 декабря 2019 года? Вот тогда бы и спрашивали… А теперь мне снова приходится думать вместе с вами. Пока вот думаю, а версии разные...

Сравнить:

(1) Автор первой, а за ним и автор второй, поздней фрески //  берут за основу одну и ту же композицию (оформление по Розенталю).

(2) Автор первой, а за ним и автор второй – пОздней фрески //  берут за основу одну и ту же композицию.

В принципе я могу взять пример из Розенталя и тоже **поставить там тире**:  Он заговорил совсем другим – серьЁзным тоном.*

Ну, это я так думаю…  Желательно **найти пример** из хорошего художественного текста, где такая конструкция используется.

Так что вопрос остается открытым: **как одиночное тире влияет на произношение, какое из определений выделено интонационно в этом случае?**

Моя последняя версия (из комментария):

А вот по поводу тире у меня появились сомнения. Мне кажется, что оно ДЕФИСНОЕ, то есть отменяет ПАУЗУ, мы получаем из двух определений одно фонетическое слово «второй-пОздней", но ударение на второй части.

Похоже на пример из Розенталя "Прилетели сюда первые ласточки — наши спортсмЕны // для участия в парусных гонках". Только там тире объединяет распространенные приложения.

Жду новых ответов.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133214/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon--------).

Comment: Дублирую последнее сообщение: Да, у него есть пример, где дефис заменён на тире, он как белая ворона, не в тему. А у Лопатина только такие и рассматриваются. Комментируется у Розенталя, есть разные справочники. Если вы произносите без паузы, то тогда нет никаких пояснительных отношений. А они здесь есть как факт. Тире не соединяет так слова, как минимум нужно слово и фраза.

Comment: "Прилетели сюда первые ласточки — наши спортсмены // для участия в парусных гонках;". Я первую часть читаю в одну фразу без паузы, затем произносительная пауза в простом предложении. Это принципиальный вопрос. Если вы слышите по-другому, то не договоримся. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111  пункт 2 в Примечаниях

Comment: По-другому. Ваш вариант не по-русски звучит. Так не говорят. Потому что "первые ласточки — наши спортсмены" не выражает единое понятие, как и "ласточки-спортсмены" (это сложное слово не верно). Когда выражается единое понятие (дефис, когда два слова), сначала должно идти основное слово, а потом приложение. Вот этот момент вы упустили. А в примерах Розенталя другое, там перелом конструкции, и даже пояснение Розенталя указывает на это. Такое бывает и в других темах, когда тире с запятой тоже. А в примере про страны единое понятие, он там не в тему, нет там такого правила, есть у Лопатина.

Comment: Мне б хотелось услышать ваш вариант произношения (то есть увидеть схему с указанием пауз и ударений). О дефисном написании. У него есть обобщенное значение - это произношение в одно фонетическое слово без  обозначения пауз но с двумя ударениями (основным и вспомогательным). Такое написание применяется в разных случаях , не только в приложениях (например, кое-где, молодо-зелено, давным-давно). А вот пример приложения: горе-охотник, золото-старушка. А все остальное из сказанного вами мне непонятно- я хочу услышать ваш вариант произношения.

Comment: Дефисом мы соединяем слова, а почему им нельзя соединить словосочетания? Графически это некорректно, а фонетически вполне возможно.

Comment: Да, но сначала должно быть основное слово (*спортсмены*), а потом приложение (*ласточки*). И главное то, что должно выражаться единое понятие. *Ласточки* — это художественное, объективно оно понятие не выражает.

Comment: Мой вариант: *Прилетели сюда первые лАсточки — [есть пауза] наши спортсмЕны [без паузы] для участия в парусных гОнках.* Это тот случай, когда от уточнения предложение продолжается, как и в этом примере Розенталя с другой темы: *При проведении подобных сложных экспериментов трудно, да и невозможно избежать отдельных ошибок.* Такие вещи называются переломом конструкции. И сейчас понимаю, что образное нельзя включать в единое понятие, если только это не нечто устойчивое.

Comment: Здесь как раз формально ласточки – определяемое существительное, а спортсмены – приложение (об этом говорит Розенталь).  А по семантике всё НАОБОРОТ, то есть НЕОБЫЧНОЕ сочетание. Поэтому его нужно  фонетически объединить в одну фразу, это решение возникает в языке как бы стихийно (он нам его «предлагает»). И это прекрасное решение! А ваш вариант чтения нехорош, он даже не похож на предложение, а выглядит как незаконченная фраза. (Надо еще где-нибудь договорить, а то система очень недовольна нами.)

Comment: *А по семантике всё НАОБОРОТ* — вот, я о семантике. Не надо ничего объединять, а то получается ласточка-спортсмен, то есть спортивная птица. А я считаю ваш нехорошим, даже более того. Далеко не все вещи можно соединить в единое понятие.

Comment: *он даже не похож на предложение, а выглядит как незаконченная фраза* — потому что перелом конструкции.

Comment: Ладно, oleedd, я ведь не настаиваю на своем мнении, а Розенталя в помощниках у нас нет. Зато разговор получился интересным, конструктивным. Спасибо за беседу. ПРизнайтесь, Не понравилось вам слово "нехорош"?  Оно вроде бы нейтральное, но почему-то обидное. Я  про него вспоминаю, когда читаю "Капитанскую дочку". Помните: — Как ты это находишь? — спросил я Швабрина, ожидая похвалы, как дани, мне непременно следуемой. Но, к великой моей досаде, Швабрин, обыкновенно снисходительный, решительно объявил, что песня моя нехороша.

Comment: Умеет вот Пушкин найти нужное словечко. Я думала, что оно вам тоже не понравится, но не была уверена.  Извините, и еще раз спасибо. With love, Sharon/

Comment: Дело не в этом слове, а в браковании. Нейтральным оно никак быть не может, там негативная оценка. У Пушкина прикольно использовано слово "объявил", объявляют объективную информацию, а субъективную — заявляют. Такая нестыковка — художественное.

Comment: Розенталь: Примечание. Второе тире в этом случае не ставится, поскольку на первом месте стоит не определяемое существительное, а приложение; ср.: *Одно из крупнейших издательств страны — Гослитиздат значительно увеличил выпуск произведений классиков мировой литературы* (сказуемое согласовано со словом *Гослитиздат*). *С утра к воздушным воротам столицы — Внуковскому аэродрому направлялось множество машин* (по смыслу машины направлялись не к «воздушным воротам столицы», а к аэродрому). Я вижу здесь перелом конструкции, особенно это доказывает первый пример, а вы почему-то — единое понятие.

Comment: oleedd, ну ладно уж, миру мир, может, вы и правы. Мне кажется, что мое мнение будет единственным в ближайшие 10-20 лет.  Остальные, вероятно, читают, как и вы, а еще вероятнее, что не читают вовсе (то есть воспринимают только зрительную информацию).

Comment: Вот ещё примеры Розенталя: *Лютейший бич небес, природы ужас — мор свирепствует в лесах* (Крылов). *Буревестник революции, создатель глубоких по содержанию романов, драм, повестей,
основоположник социалистического реализма — Горький оставил неизгладимый след в литературе и в общественной жизни.* Сможете прочитать в одно фонетическое слово, особенно последнее?

Comment: Это разные конструкции. Первое предложение из нашей темы, а второе: обособление с помощью тире оборота с причинным значением (= будучи). А у Крылова паузы на месте тире точно нет.

Comment: Но у Крылова пояснение, никак не единое понятие. *Это разные конструкции* — на самом там такая же конструкция ("будучи" в первом тоже подходит), и не важно, образное там или нет. Кстати, эти два примера из одного пункта Розенталя. А другое — когда замена дефиса на тире (§ 154: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80). А Розенталь об этом не говорит, но пример про "страны" про это, он там не должен быть.

Comment: А я как раз и говорю, что Розенталь смешал в одной теме разные конструкции, что не есть хорошо.  Но для того времени, может, это было простительно, а сейчас пора бы разобраться "кто есть кто" И потом, я объединяю элементы по фонетике, а не по семантике, так как их грамматика нестандартная, поэтому ее надо выделить в одну фонетическую единицу. Я не говорю - про  единое понятие.

Comment: У Розенталя только пример со странами не в тему. Единое понятие — следствие такого произношения. Иначе пояснение, а при нём не должно быть слитного произношения. И интонация при пояснении соответствующая (отличается).