# Постановка тире при уточнении

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения

Дано предложение:

*Я  даже позволю себе назвать этот памятник типичным примером **придворного – рафинированного** искусства.*

Тире смотрится неплохо, но можно ли найти для него конкретное правило? Кстати, такой вариант встречается в тексте не один раз.

Comment: У вас был подобный вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457459

Comment: Подобный вопрос был,  и подобные примеры встречаются часто, а вот правила мне тогда никто не нашел. А теперь я могу обосновать тире ссылкой на Розенталя, если кто-нибудь поинтересуется, конечно.

Comment: Оно подходит под первый пункт, который нашёл Александр, но Розентяль написал слишком коротко, лишь два примера, и только с глаголами. Думаю, что при замене запятой на тире интонация меняется (даже значительно).

Comment: Разумеется, меняется, а иначе зачем мне тогда тире. Вместо перечислительной  интонация становится взаимообусловленной, в данном случае  пояснительной, как я думаю. Взаимообусловленность бывает разная, но обозначается она одинаково - знаком тире. А вы бы лучше поискали правило на другой вопрос - о восклицательном знаке в середине предложения.

Comment: Просто помню, что в том вопросе вы говорили, что, по Розенталю, перед определением, носящим характер пояснения, ставится запятая. При тире тоже пояснение, но более сильное - одно понятие определяется через другое.

Comment: Всё так и было, только правила не было. Я эту тему у Розенталя как-то просмотрела, а она может быть полезной.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Розенталя рассматриваются похожие случаи.

> ***Синонимия запятой и тире** с сохранением присущих каждому из этих
> знаков препинания смысловых и интонационных оттенков встречается в
> ряде случаев: 1) **между однородными членами предложения при бессоюзном
> их соединении***
>
> Превратила всё в шутку сначала, поняла — принялась
> укорять (Бл.) — постановка запятой вместо тире ослабила бы оттенок
> следствия;
>
> http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=190

Т. е. по Розенталю, замена запятой на тире между однородными членами предложения *усиливает оттенок следствия* (здесь в направлении: "придворного, а значит, рафинированного искусства").

Comment: В данном примере нет глаголов с оттенком следствия. Тире при следствии - другое правило.

Comment: Alex_ander, спасибо за ответ. Даже если здесь нет оттенка следствия, то он мне и не нужен. Важно само правило о вариативности знаков. Здесь скорее пояснение: придворного, то есть рафинированного искусства. То же  самое можно записать просто через запятую: придворного, рафинированного искусства (это практически однородные определения,  раскрывающие общий признак). В любом случае я запятую имею право заменить тире, вот что важно.